# Ionic vue Mobile to communicate with odoo

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, odoo, android-emulator

i am unable to get my android emulator to login to odoo locally running server.

when i spin up the ionic app. it is only the browser that communicates with odoo.

However, the mobile does not. He just shows the login page